# How do I trigger a Python script from Dragon?

Tags: python, medical

I'm processing radiology dictations to make hard line breaks at the default 70 characters using textwrap in python 3.6.

This will be used at the point of dictation when copying the report from Voice Recognition into the RIS for signing.  That's why the clipboard manipulation is used.

This is working but I'm wondering if I can make it more efficient. I'd also like to have Dragon trigger it as a part of scripting and I'm not sure where to start looking for info on how to trigger a python script from inside a dragon script.

```
from tkinter import Tk
import textwrap

report = Tk()
# Prevent the window from showing
report.withdraw()
try:
    uncutText = report.clipboard_get() # Gets clipboard text
except:
    uncutText = "The Clipboard Was empty"

cutText = textwrap.wrap(uncutText)
report.clipboard_clear()
for line in cutText:
    report.clipboard_append("\n")  # Add CR for each line pasted
    report.clipboard_append(line)  # Paste to Clipboard
report.update()  # updates clipboard
report.destroy()  # destroys the report object
```

Comment: What type of efficiency are you looking to achieve? What would you like the code to do that it doesn't do now?

Comment: Hello G_L and welcome to the site.  We generally try to keep questions to the point, so I went ahead and edited yours down a bit.

Comment: Mack.  Thank you.  Your guidance is much appreciated. Because I'm new to programming, I don't know if there would be a better paradigm than modifying it on the clipboard.  Such as writing to a file (which is the next goal to accumulate data for parsing).